# How to get button inside of RecyclerView item

Tags: android

How do i get a specific view inside of a RecyclerView item? For example I have a floating action button inside of a recyclerview item. The recyclerview card can swipe to trigger an event (new activity) and when the user swipes i am making the fab invisible. I want so that when the user returns back to the activity with the recyclerview, the fab is visible again.

I've tried to implement this a few ways, but for some reason it's taking the fab from the NEXT card/item and placing it on the original card/item that was swiped. This is a problem because the next card might have a different colored fab or no fab at all. What is happening is that it's taking the most recent viewholder item, even if the previous one is the one I want to deal with.

So i need a way to reference the fab in the current item. I'm currently setting it to currentFab = holder.mFab (but again, it's taking the most recent holder item even though it's not the one I pressed on). I need a way to reference the fab in a specific item.

Comment: Can you add the code for what you've got so far? It will probably be easier to debug than an English description.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried something similar in the past, I've added the Swipe function in "onBindViewHolder ", Using a Swipe Library.

What I have made is, A CardView, Inside it there are 2 Strings, And a Button, this Button will be invisible according to specific conditions, So because it's inside onBindVewHolder, it was easy to make some edits on the button.

Here's a sample :

```
        holder.Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.Button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Ofcourse this isn't a "fully working code" it's just an example, Plus you didn't put any code that you have tried.